# Updating View from socket connection

Tags: android, sockets, user-interface

I'm writing an application that needs to receive data from a socket every 10 seconds or so, and then draw a view on the screen to graph that data. Unfortunately, I'm pretty new to Android and am having some trouble understanding how to make this work. I've been doing some reading on handlers, but I'm not quite sure how to make use of them. Can you use these with a class that extends a View, or do I not need to use these at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a Handler seems to be the correct approach since you are updating your UI from a non UI thread (at least you should be!)...You can either use the Handler like this, or do the data processing from your Activity and call CustomView.draw() from a Handler in your Activity.

```
public class CustomView extends View {

    public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public CustomView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        ...
        startThread();
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        ...
        //Do drawing...canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap) or w/e
        ...
    }

    private void startThread() {
        Thread thread = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    doSocketRequest();
                } catch (SocketException e) { // Or w/e exceptions are applicable
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    Message msg = new Message();
                    //msg.obj = ObjectContainingInformationTheHandlerMightNeed
                    mHandler.sendMessage(msg);//replace 0 w/ a message if need be

                }
            }
        };
    }

    private void doSocketRequest() {
        ...
        //Do your socket stuff here
        ...
    }

    private Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            ...
            //Do graph processing stuff
            ...
            invalidate(); //forces onDraw
        }
    };

}
```

Comment: This was very helpful. Right now I have an activity that is doing the socket communication, and then this needs to call another class that draws the view. I guess I made it much more complex than I needed to. Thanks!